# Creating a template class in C++ on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, class, templates, datatemplate

I'm supposed to create a template class for an assignment, but I'm getting lots of different errors that I don't really understand, can someone please help me? I have attached the cp and header files that I wrote. I know this is probably very simple but I'm new to this, thank you!

```
#ifndef __Template_example__Initialisedchecker__ 
#define __Template_example__Initialisedchecker__ 
#include <stdio.h>
template <class data>
class Initialisedchecker
{
private:
    data item;
    bool definedOrN;
public:

    Initialisedchecker()
    {
        definedOrN = false;
    }

    void setItem(const data&)
    {
        std::cin >> item;
        definedOrN = true;
    }


    void displayItem()
    {
        if (definedOrN)
        {
            std::cout << item;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "error, your item is undefined";
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

And this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Initialisedchecker.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    item <int> x;
    displayItem();
    x = 5;
    displayItem();
}
```

Sorry, I forgot to add the errors I'm getting, the header file doesn't give any errors, but in the main, it says:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'display item'  ,   
Use of undeclared identifier 'item'  ,  
Use of undeclared identifier 'x'  ,  
Expected a '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

Comment: I see no error output attached

Comment: The error output you show is **not** what your compiler gives you. It would never complain about an undeclared identifier which contains a space. Why not copy/paste the real output? Please take the time to be **exact** if you expect strangers on the internet to take the time to help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class template is called `Initialisedchecker`, not `item`. And you need to call the member function on the object. You need:

```
int main()
{
    Initialisedchecker <int> x;
    x.displayItem();
    // this is strange: x = 5;
    // maybe use:
    // x.setItem( 5 );
    x.displayItem();

}
```